# upload local image to amazon cloud using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying uploading the local folder structure to Amazon cloud using NodeJS. I am able to successfully upload the folder but not able to upload image files inside that folder.

Code:

```
function uploadFile(token, filePath, title, parentNodeId, cb) {
    var url = amazonEndpoint.contentUrl;
    url += 'nodes?suppress=deduplication'; // REMOVE SUPPRESS WHEN ADDING HANDLING FOR DUPES!

    var parents = [];
    if (parentNodeId) parents.push(parentNodeId);

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("metadata", JSON.stringify({
    "name": title,
    "kind": "FILE",
    "parents": parents}));
    form.append("content", fs.createReadStream(filePath));
    var formData = qs.stringify(form);
    formData = JSON.stringify(form);

    request({
    "headers": {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.access_token,
        'Content-Length': formData.length,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent' : 'carbonite byoc'
    },
    uri: url,
    body: formData,
    method: "POST"
    }, function(err, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode == 400) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // @TODO
    } else {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        cb(data.id);
    }
    });

}
```